# const char* const array initialization with const variables

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

```
const char* const successArray[2] = {"Y", "Z"};

const char* const successA = "A";
const char* const successB = "B";

const char* const failArray1[2] = {successA, successB};
const char* const failArray2[2] = {&(successA[0]), &(successB[0])};
```

I think I fully understand the differences of const char* vs const char* const and * vs []. But why do the last 2 lines fail with

```
error: initializer element is not constant
const char* const failArray1[2] = {successA, successB};
```

Initializing a const array by const variables should clearly be possible, should'nt it? What am I missing?

Comment: The value of a variable declared `const` is not the sort of constant that can be used in the initializer of a variable of static storage duration in C. (Note that C23 will have the `constexpr` storage class for that sort of thing.)

Comment: @IanAbbot Thanks for the reply. So in say C99 this is generally not possible and I have to use the strings represented by "A" and "B" twice, requiring twice the storage on my platform?

Comment: The storage for identical string literals may share the same storage, but it is up to the whim of the compiler. You could use named arrays of `const char` and refer to them from several places, e.g.: `const char successA[] = "A";` `const char successB[] = "B";` `const char* const failArray1[2] = {successA, successB};` `const char* const failArray2[2] = {successA, successB};`.

Comment: … (cont.d) Technically, the compiler *could* store the string literals that are used to initialize `char successA[]` and `char successB[]`, but in practice the compiler will optimize out the storage of string literals that are only used as initializers for arrays of characters because nothing can refer to them.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems I still have not understood all the intricacies of * vs [] in the c langauge., It works if the source of the initializer is an array type, and why it will not decaying to a pointer in that case. Could you maybe point me to the part of the C standard or another reference where it is described why it must be an array initialized by the "A" const char* and cannot be of that type in the first place? Thanks again, as this will most likely solve my issue of reusing string memory.

Comment: @gaiuscosades: C 2018 6.7.9 14 says an array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal. C 2018 6.7.9 4 says initializers for static objects shall be constant expressions or string literals, and C 2018 6.6 specifies what constant expressions are.

Comment: An array in an initializer that is not a string literal used to initialize a character array *does* decay to a pointer to the first element of the array. If the array in the initializer has static storage duration, then the pointer it decays to is an *address constant* which is a *constant expression*.

Comment: An *lvalue* is not a *constant expression*. An array is an lvalue (although it is not a *modifiable lvalue*) but when an array decays to a pointer (as it does when it appears in an initializer (unless it is a string literal used to initialize an array of characters)), the resulting pointer is not an lvalue, so that does not prevent the pointer being an *address constant* if the array had static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

The top-level "constness" of `successA` and `successB` prevents you from writing code like this:

```
/* none of these lines will compile */
successA = "C";
successA++;
successA--;
```

When that identifier is used as an rvalue in expressions, you are effectively copying it temporarily and the constness is irrelevant:

```
/* top-level const doesn't matter - "successA" won't be modified anyway */
myfunc(successA);
x = successA + 1;
```

When initialising your `failArray1`, the compiler doesn't care about the `const` of your previous identifiers. It sees identifiers referring to some values. Those expressions are not considered constant, hence the error.

Comment: I see. So there is no way of having two const char* initialize to point at exactly the same string (same memory location at linking) while maintaining constness for type safety when using?

Comment: @gaiuscosades: Define an object with the string, as with `const char StringA[] = "A";`, and then use that as the initializer, as with `const char *const Array[] = { StringA, StringB };`. While the C standard does not specify that values of variables can be used as constants for initializers, it does specify their addresses can be used as initializers (and the array `StringA` is automatically converted to the address of its first element, so it is an address being used for the initializer).

Comment: @EricPostpischil. Thanks! Yes this works, but this has the downside that a variable of type `const char const []` cannot be a member of a struct (which I need for my implementation) so I now have to build a point of redirection, having `const char const []` variables holding the real strings, and having all `const char* const` and `const char* const []` pointing to them, for actual usage resolving them. Still this seems to be the way to go, thanks!